# Disable pop-up hints

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

Every time i start the game and join a server i get these annoying pop-up hints that won't leave until i have done what they want me to do, (zoom in with a scope, press 'e' to look at the gun).
So right now what i do is join a random server, do all the common things they tell me to and then join a proper competition server to play.
Is there a command line i can add to my configuration file to get rid of them ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Go to the options in CounterStrike : GO and disable the Game Instructor Messages as seen in this screenshot:

[image: Game Instructor Screenshot]

This should stop the game from annoying you in the future.

Another method would be to open `config.cfg` in your CS GO Folder (after you removed the mentioned read-only flag) with a text editor of your choice, such as Notepad++. You can find the file in `X:\Steam\SteamApps\common\Counter-Strike Global Offensive\csgo\cfg` (X being the hard drive you installed it on). Then find the line where it says `gameinstructor_enable` and set it to 0 or, if it is not there, add `gameinstructor_enable=0` at the bottom of the file. That should do the trick.

Comment: but the problem is that my config erases this parameter every time i restart the game ! isn't there a command line in my config associated to that ?

Comment: Your config cannot erase this option. Edit your config file into your OP if there is a problem with it and be more specific.

Comment: my config file is read only so when i change the in game settings, it cannot write them in my file.

Comment: @user3714670 I updated my answer

Answer (score 3):

It is now: `This PC/Windows C/ windows (86x)/Steam/userdata/(OWN ID SHOULD BE ONE FOLDER)/730/local/cfg`

Go through the config file and check if you don't have any binds to enable gameinstructor. (That was my problem I got so frustrated; my buddies just did `bind mouse1 "attack;gameinstructor_enable"` or something).

Comment: Your friends might be geniuses.  That is a sweet prank due to both how harmless it is and how annoying that problem would be.

Answer (score 0):

You can also enter

```
gameinstructor_enable 0
```

in the developer console.